# Ordering descending in jOOQ when order by parameters are numbers/positions

Tags: java, jooq

I have this jOOQ code, it works fine, however the `order by` should be descending column 1 and descending column 3, but `.orderBy(1,3)` has number parameters that cannot have a `.desc()` method. How can this be accomplished?

```
    Predictions p = PREDICTIONS.as("p");
    Banks b = BANKS.as("b");

    List<Prediction> list = context
            .select (inline(1).as("SELECTED"),p.EXEC_ID,p.DATASET_NAME,p.DATE_TIME)
            .from(p)
            .join(b)
            .on(b.SK.eq(p.BANK_SK))
            .where(p.EXEC_ID.in(execIds))
            .unionAll(context.
              select(inline(0).as("SELECTED"),p.EXEC_ID,p.DATASET_NAME,p.DATE_TIME)
                .from(p)
                .join(b)
                .on(b.SK.eq(p.BANK_SK))
                .where(p.EXEC_ID.notIn(execIds)))
            .orderBy(1,3)
            .fetch()
            .into(Prediction.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DSL.inline(1)` too, so your orderBy with static imports may look like:

`.orderBy(inline(1).desc(), inline(3).desc())`.

It might also be mentioned in the JavaDoc of the [`orderBy`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SelectOrderByStep.html#orderBy(int...)) method.